# How to add a list to a data frame in R?

Tags: r, list, join, merge

I have 2 tables as below:

```
a = read.table(text=' a b
1 c
1 d
2 c
2 a
2 b
3 a
', head=T)



b = read.table(text=' a c
1 x i
2 y j 
3 z k
', head=T)
```

And I want result to be like this:

```
1 x i c d
2 y j c a b
3 z k a
```

Originally I thought to use tapply to transform them to lists (eg. aa = tapply(a[,2], a[,1], function(x) paste(x,collapse=","))), then append it back to table b,  but I got stuck...

Any suggestion to do this?
Thanks a million.

Comment: You want to merge two data.frames.

Comment: Why don't you store it in a list? A data.frame is a list with certain restriction, e.g. that all elements of the list have the same length, which does not apply to your data. Even though you could simulate, that all elements have the same length using `""`, you would probably mess up your data.

Comment: @rmuc8, I thought that too.. but for example, (bb = tapply(b[,1:2], b[,1], function(x) paste(x,collapse=","))) gives me error of "arguments must have same length".. what to do?

Comment: @Pascal , yup, I thought to merge 2 frames, take the element 1 for example, I don't want result to be 1 x i c, 1 x i  d, I want 1 x i c d, that is why I am stuck. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
mapply(FUN = c, 
       lapply(split(b, row.names(b)), function(x) as.character(unlist(x, use.names = FALSE))), 
       split(as.character(a$b), a$a), 
       SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
# $`1`
# [1] "x" "i" "c" "d"
# 
# $`2`
# [1] "y" "j" "c" "a" "b"
# 
# $`3`
# [1] "z" "k" "a"
```